# How to Segue to the same ViewController via multiple segues from the same TableViewController

Tags: objective-c, delegates, viewcontroller, segue

I have a static TableViewController that has two static cells: A departure airport and an arrival airport. Both segue to another TableViewController that allows a user to select an airport and defines the original TVC as the delegate to pass the object back. What I don't know how to do is identify which property is being set when an airport is selected; the departure or arrival airport when the selection is passed back via a delegate. What I've started implementing is a property on the AirportListTVC that is set via the prepareForSegue method and then passed back to the delegate when a selection is made. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Passing information to a new UIViewController is generally tricky - and using the automatic segues in Interface Builder doesn't really allow you to easily pass info.  Basically I'd suggest two ways (it sounds like you're using one):

1) Use the Interface Builder segues and use prepareForSegue to pass any information you have to the new UIViewController.

2) Name the UIViewController in Interface Builder (the Identifier) and then present it yourself using `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` as follows - using a Navigation Controller in this case to present:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [viewController storyboard];
MyViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyVC"];
[vc configureWithMyData:myData];
[navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

It is a case of picking which suits you though.  Obviously you could also create controllers totally in code.

There are some things to consider here - for example these two methods cause the new UIViewController to be actually initialised/viewDidLoad at different points (I can expand on this if this helps).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm actually having no issues performing the segue and setting properties. What I can't figure out is how to determine which segue was performed from the Master to the Detail TVC, so that when the Detail TVC passes the value selected back to the Master I know which property to set.  I'm using CoreData and sharing a Managed Object Context if that helps give me a different take on how to accomplish this. Right now I'm setting a property on the Detail TVC so I know which segue was performed and passing that back along with the value selected on the Detail TVC.

Comment: Are you using an MVC design pattern? The Detail TVC updates the model, closes and then the Master VC retrieves the updated information from the model when it re-appears.  If you're talking about two bits of information, you could probably just update the view...

Comment: I am using a MVC design pattern.  On the MasterTVC, I am creating an object in the MOC.  I'm then segueing to the DetailTVC and that DetailTVC is specifying the Master TVC as it's delegate to pass the selected object to so that it can be saved into the MOC.  Should I be passing a pointer to the object that is created in the MasterTVC to the DetailTVC and making updates to the model directly from the DetailTVC?

Comment: Hard to tell from this, but that sounds better.